# Is it possible for EC2 instances to be in a "pending" state when CloudFormation has a status of "CREATE_COMPLETE"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have some scripts that does some operations after CloudFormation finishes bringing up a stack. Part of the scripts include querying EC2 for a list of instances based on a filter.

Is it possible that an EC2 instance is in a "pending" state after CloudFormation reports that a stack has completed?

Answer (score 0):

yes. it's possible. 
cloudformation finished issuing the calls to spin up the instances and completed the stack creation while the instances are still coming up.

you can if you want you can definitely wait for the instance to come up and signal to the cloudformation stack that it's up. see:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html#deployment-walkthrough-cfn-signal

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-waitcondition.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html

or

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-waitcondition.html